# "No matter when" OR "it doesn't matter when"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, phrase-meaning, conjunctions

In the book Practical English Usage, on page number 253:

*"Because no matter who, what, etc act like conjunctions, they must be used with
two clauses.*

*- No matter when you come, you’ll be welcome, (but not No matter when you come.)*

*to introduce just one clause, we can use It doesn't matter.*

*- It doesn’t matter when you come."*

I haven't understood what this quoted text means. can somebody tell me what it means?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

"It doesn't matter [question-word]..." can be used to introduce one clause, or to link two clauses.

> It doesn't matter what they say.
> It doesn't matter what they say, I will always support you.

The phrase "No matter [question word]..." has the same meaning, but it can only be used to connect two clauses. The question-word can be who, when, what, which, etc. Here are a couple of examples.

> [Clause 1] no matter [question-word] [clause 2]
> I will support you no matter what they say

> No matter [question-word] [clause 2], [clause 1]
> No matter what they say, I will support you